# Unable to redirect from http to https (htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, https, xampp

I am using XAMPP, CodeIgniter and a SSL certificate from GoDaddy installed in our server. My htaccess configuration is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com[NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

When I enter https://example.com in the browser, it works fine. Also if I put only [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), but when I enter only http://example.com the page will not load. GoDaddy gave me support changing the htaccess file in many ways, but none worked.

Something about my apache configuration? SSL? XAMP?

I also cleared cache, used other computers and also phones (incognito and normal mode).

Comment: I use `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{PATH_INFO} [R=301,L]`, not posting this as answer, as I don't know too much about your setup

Comment: @Vickel Using `PATH_INFO` in that redirect is rather unique to your site, that's certainly not what most should be using here.

Comment: "the page won't load" - what happens exactly? When you "put only `www.example.com`" what request is actually be made to your server? If GoDaddy are your host/SSL cert provider then they really should know what you need to do here since this is quite likely server specific that only your webhost would know, without having to guess. (You're not really using XAMPP on a live server are you?)

Comment: You also should check whether that SSL certificate really covers _both_ host names, so `example.com` _and_ `www.example.com`. Both are completely different things for the http server. And a redirection from http to https will only work with a certificate precisely matching the requested host name ...

Comment: @MrWhite, yes, for now we are using XAMPP. 

When I load the website using www in front, the page is redirected to https. It fails and say “took to long to respond” when I put http in front. Works fine with www and https in front. But the site is not redirected when using http in URL

Comment: Hello @arkascha, how do I check that in the certificate? I bough it on GoDaddy.

Comment: Update:

I see that the redirect works perfect when visiting the website inside the company network. Using http, https and www.

But when I try http://example.com same outside the network I get the following message from the browser (Brave, Chrome, Edge, Safari): example.com took too long to respond.